# underscore js : compare key object to array keys objects if exist remove existing add new

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

i try to compare obj id to array objects id , remove object id =1 from array and `array.push(obj);`

```
   var array =[{"id":1,"name":"amine"},{"id":2,"name":"aymen"}] ;
    var obj = {"id":1, "name":"youssef"};

 array.push(obj);                  
 var newArray = _.uniq(array , function(item, key, id) {
                            return item.name;
                        });

console.log(newArray) ;
```

newArray =[{"id":1,"name":"amine"},{"id":2,"name":"aymen"}] ;

i want newArray = [{"id":2,"name":"aymen"},{"id":1,"name":"youssef"}] ;`

can anyone help me brains ;)

Comment: console.log() ? it's just too show you the result of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to remove any entry in the array that has that `id`, then add the new object with that `id`. It seems like the simplest thing is to do those two things, in that order:

```
array = _.filter(array, function(entry) { return entry.id != obj.id; });
array.push(obj);
```

Live example:

```js
var array = [{"id": 1, "name": "amine"}, {"id": 2, "name": "aymen"}];
var obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "youssef"
};

array = _.filter(array, function(entry) {
  return entry.id != obj.id;
});
array.push(obj);

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you don't like using `_.filter`, you could use `_.find` and then `Array#splice`:

```
var index = _.find(array, function(entry) { return entry.id == obj.id; });
if (index !== undefined) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
array.push(obj);
```

Live example:

```js
var array = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "amine"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "aymen"
}];
var obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "youssef"
};

var index = _.find(array, function(entry) {
  return entry.id == obj.id;
});
if (index !== undefined) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
array.push(obj);

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i try also

```
array = _.without(array , _.findWhere(array , {id: obj.id}));
array.push(obj);
```

and it work ;)!